# Xamarin Android with appcompat makes all my text white

Tags: android, xamarin, material-design

I'm trying to understand and implement the Material Theme for my Xamarin Android app. I've read the resources like [this blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/) and [the Android documentation](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). But I guess I'm still missing something important.

In short: I've setup my Parent theme to 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. And all the text (textview) are white. And I want to stick as much as possible to the Material Design guidelines.

**values/styles.xml**

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  </style>
```

**values-v21**

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
  </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="MaterialDesignTest1.MaterialDesignTest1" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="21" />
    <application android:label="MaterialDesignTest1"  android:theme="@style/MyTheme"></application>
</manifest>
```

**Mainactivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "MaterialDesignTest1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{
    /* Omitted the viewpager & tablayout code */
}
```

And the FilmsFragment.axml that I'm loading into a tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Fragment that shows all Starwars Films information 1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The result is shown in the attached image:
[image: White font in the fragment]

When I change the parent to `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` or `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`:

[image]

Setting the SDK Target to 23 changes a bit, but still white fonts:

[image]

What property gives all the fonts the white color? And why?

Xamarin: 4.0.0.1717

Xamarin Android: 6.0.0.35

All Xamarin Support packages: 23.1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set specific colors for your app make sure within your MyTheme.Base you add

```
   <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

You should also probably be using AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentAcitivty.